# View state Property null

Tags: asp.net

I m getting null  in checking view state null  condition  but ViewState name is not null , I enabled ViewState property  .This methods  calling  inside a for each loop .In some objects View state not null but majority getting null.I haven't set ViewState in any other places.

```
private void SetSelectedDates(string viewStateName, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar calanderControl)
        {
            var variable = ViewState[viewStateName];
            var dateTimeList = new List<DateTime>();

            if (ViewState[viewStateName] != null)
            {
                dateTimeList = (List<DateTime>)ViewState[viewStateName];
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: http://www.codingwith.net/2008/01/viewstate-backed-properties-part-one.html

Comment: @user3136682 Are you getting any error?Can you show us where  are you assigning value to `ViewState[viewstateName]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.Put double quotes in `viewstatename`

```
private void SetSelectedDates(string viewStateName, System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar calanderControl)
        {
            var variable = ViewState[viewStateName];
            var dateTimeList = new List<DateTime>();

            if (ViewState[viewStateName] != null)
            {
                dateTimeList = (List<DateTime>)ViewState["viewStateName"];
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
ViewState["viewStateName"]
```

> View state data is stored in one or more hidden fields as
>   base64-encoded strings. You can access view state information using
>   the page's ViewState property, which exposes a dictionary object.
>   Because the data in view state is stored as a string, only objects
>   that can be serialized can be stored.